# Creating apk file out of a Progressive Web App

Tags: apk, progressive-web-apps

Is there any way for creating an .apk file from a Progressive web app (PWA) so that I can add it to play store?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). It allows you to host web apps as Android or IOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328396/how-to-create-progressive-web-app-apk-any-type-of-file-that-can-be-distributed-i), I think you have a lot of option to this including:

- Using Chrome for Android, it generates and sign .apk file using
  [WebPack](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin)
- Alternative solution is wrapping with [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/) kind of hybrid solution
  for distribution of PWA apps in apps store.
- [TWA(Trusted Web Activity)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/using-twa), which was recently posted in the PWA
  documentation

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use tools like [PWA2APK](https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk/), in order to convert existing PWA's to APK file, which in turn can be uploaded on Google Play store.

Answer (score 0):

this is easy way to do it: https://github.com/xtools-at/Android-PWA-Wrapper
You can build your APK, or even better: Android bundle, which has smaller size in google play store! It is free and you can choose your own app name. In PWA2APK it is paid.