# Can you install a PWA from the manifest file?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

Is there a way to install / launch a PWA with the manifest file only? (without requiring that the user launches a browser and load the app URL first). All research seems to point to users needing to first launch the URL, then tell the browser to install the web app (add to home screen).

We're developing an enterprise app that will be installed on mobile devices that are very restricted and browser access for end users may be limited. We were hoping the manifest file could somehow be used to launch / install the PWA without first launching a local browser.

Thanks! 
Marc

Comment: Possibly related: [How to create Progressive web app apk/any type of file that can be distributed in a enterprise devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49328396/295004)

Comment: You don't need APK files just the correct options in your manifest/PWA. Ok the "first" time the user has to visit your web-site but then they will/can be prompted to Install the PWA. From then on they can see the app in the app draw and click on the homescreen icon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Progressive web app apk/any type of file that can be distributed in a enterprise devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328396/how-to-create-progressive-web-app-apk-any-type-of-file-that-can-be-distributed-i)

Answer (score 0):

Found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328396/how-to-create-progressive-web-app-apk-any-type-of-file-that-can-be-distributed-i) that seems to provide some options via APK files distributed on Play Store. We'll try this out and see if it works for us.

Answer (score 0):

If your app have passed the [Lighthouse PWA audit](https://www.webpagetest.org/lighthouse) You should try this tool,  https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk/