# PWA not installing as apk

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA that prompts for installation. Lighthouse and other debugging shows everything is OK.

When I install it, the PWA is added as a shortcut and not like an APK in the app screen.

I've noticed this thread: [PWA not installed as WebApk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610042/pwa-not-installed-as-webapk) but it doesnt give me a solution that works.

I've also noticed this thread: [Chrome Badge shows on 'Add To Homescreen' installed PWA (Only shortcut is installing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217259/chrome-badge-shows-on-add-to-homescreen-installed-pwa-only-shortcut-is-instal)

and it doesnt help since I'm signed in to google play on the device.